# Print Iframe content only on page load

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to print Iframed content on load. However the code I have is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var newWin = document.getElementById('print').contentWindow;
newWin.document.write(body);
newWin.document.close(); //important!
newWin.focus(); //IE fix
newWin.print();
}
</script>

<iframe id="print" src="http://www.davearbogast.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/MAINTENANCESPECIALCoupon.jpg" width="300" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: `body` is undefined.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I have an iframe embedded on a page, I would like only the iframe content to print on page load.